# Documentation on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i'm new to Cloud Functions.

I'm noticing that there is a day and night difference between how to do something in Firestore through code and how to do it through Cloud Functions.

e.g. in app code:

```js
addDoc(collection(db, "images/"), {
  imageURL: downloadURL,
  imageName: image.name,
  createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  user: user,
});
console.log(image.name + " has been uploaded");
```

cloud functions(found from a tutorial):

```js
exports.imageUploadDocCreate = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {
const images = admin.firestore().collection("images");
return images.add({
        imageURL: object.imageLink,
        createdAt: object.timeCreated,
        imageName: object.name,
        user: object.id,
      });
}
```

Where do i find the cloud functions code documentation and i don't mean the structure of a triggers like `onCreate`, `onDelete` etc for Firestore or `onDelete`, `onFinalize` for Storage or chron jobs but i mean documentation to manipulate Firestore data(for example) within a Cloud Function like a specific trigger, http request etc.

I want to convert some of my in-app code to a function.

Is there documentation on this? Is it part of Node.js or what?

Answer (score 0):

Within a Cloud Function you're typically using the Admin SDK for Node.js, so be sure to switch to those code samples when navigating the documentation - such as here in the documentation on [adding data to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js).

In general, the two code snippets you share look so different because they use a different syntax:

- The first code snippet uses the newer modular syntax that was introduced in version 9 of the JavaScript SDK. To learn more about this syntax, the reason for the change, and how to upgrade code to it, see the documentation on [upgrading from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)
- The second code snippet uses the classic namespaced syntax that existed before already. You can still use this syntax on the latest SDK versions too by [importing the `compat` path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_compat).